# The use of "react" as a transitive verb

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I am quite familiar with the meaning of "react" as "change in response to a stimulus". For example "She reacted angrily when scolded".

However in the [Merriam Webster definition of React](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/react) in the "transitive verb" section it says "To cause to react". Is this use common?

Can I say for example "The thief used his finger to react the infrared sensor"?

(meaning using the finger to cause the sensor to react)

EDIT:

What would be a good way to rewrite the above sentence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Collins English dictionary, this meaning is the least common:

> [react](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/react) in American
>   (riˈækt ; rēaktˈ)
>
> verb intransitive
>
> 1. to act in return or reciprocally
> 2. to act in opposition
> 3. to act in a reverse way; go back to a former condition, stage, etc.
> 4. to respond to a stimulus; be affected by some influence, event, etc.
> 5. Chemistry
>      to act with another substance in producing a chemical change
>
> verb transitive
>
> 6. to cause to react; specif., to produce a chemical change in

Note that it's about "react" in American English. As for British English, the same dictionary says nothing about the transitive *react*.

Speaking of your sentence, I'd say *The thief used his finger to start the infrared sensor.* I wouldn't use "react" because we are not talking about a chemical reaction.

Comment: it also added that is specific to chemical changes. So what would be a good way to rewrite the sentence with the thief and the sensor?

Comment: @KansaiRobot Rather than *react*, you can use something like *engage*, *activate*, or *trigger*.

Comment: @KansaiRobot I've edited my answer.